# Checkbox in Semantic UI

Tags: checkbox, semantic-ui

I'm trying to do checkbox in Semantic UI, but it doesn't work and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
I'm including jquery, semantic.min.js, checkbox.js and semantic.min.css, then I add this code:

```
$('.ui.checkbox')
    .checkbox()
;
```

There is console output, but image of checkbox doesn't change.

Answer (score 8):

I've solved this problem to write jQuery's code like this:

```
$(document).ready(
        function () {
            $('.ui.checkbox')
                    .checkbox()
                    ;
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you wrap it on proper Div tags?

```
<div class="ui checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="fun">
  <label>I enjoy having fun</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to mask the original checkbox like this

```
<div class="ui checkbox">
  <input name="subscribe" type="checkbox">
  <label>Subscribe to Email News letters</label>
</div>
```